# Passing XSL String to Javascript

Tags: javascript, xslt

I'm trying to pass a string from XSL to Javascript. I was able to pass integers but it doesn't seem to accept strings.  The following is the basic structure of my code.  If I delete "Test" from "Test 1" I do get the alertbox with the number 1. But once there's text inside, the alertbox does not come up.

XML:

```
<TEST>
  <TITLE>Test 1</TITLE>
<TEST>

<TEST>
  <TITLE>Test 2</TITLE>
<TEST>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//TEST">
<xsl:call-template name="TEST_TEMPLATE"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

...

```
<xsl:template name="TEST_TEMPLATE">

<script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[var title = ]]><xsl:value-of select="./TITLE" /><![CDATA[;

alert(title);]]>
</script>
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are not "passing a string from XSL to Javascript". Your XSLT code is generating HTML, part of which happens to be a script element. It is easy to see that the script element you are generating contains the text:

var title = Test 1;

which will obviously not do anything useful when it comes to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

You need qoutes around the title. The template you have just outputs the value of the string, but it has to be in qoutes to be valid javascript. I think this would work:

```
<xsl:template name="TEST_TEMPLATE">

<script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[var title = "]]><xsl:value-of select="./TITLE" /><![CDATA[";

alert(title);]]>
</script>
```